# How to update collection in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

```
        post = {
            'username': username,
            'password': password,
            'exp': 0,
            'level': 1
        }
```

This is what I have so far. If I do something like:

```
post['exp'] = 10
```

the change isn't permanent. I've looked it up and there's an update function but they all seem to involve ids and sets, which I'm not that familiar with. Could someone give me advice on updating a value in a post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the find_one_and_update function with your pymongo connection:

```
# Assuming your connecting to a local database
conn = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
collection = conn['database_name']['collection_name']
# Lets say you use a username to find your document
collection.find_one_and_update(
    {'username': 'yasong'}, {'$set': {'exp': 10}}
)
```